# How to parameterize the Source and Target Connection using Parameter file in Informatica Cloud?

Tags: cloud, parameter-passing, informatica, informatica-cloud

I''ve tried parameterizing Source and Target connections in Informatica cloud. But i'm unable to do so.Because while creating Mapping_task itself it's asking for  connection information from a drop down list.

Is der any way to accomplish parameterization of Source and Target connections using parameter file in Informatica Cloud like Power Center?

Comment: Hi, Did you got answer for that?